# 2 axis in the same chart (left and right)

Tags: qlikview

I have problem, i want to include two axis dimention-y(left and right) in the same chart with the 2 dimention in y-axis. i have this.
[image: property]

[the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5THeq.png.)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change axis (posicion?) of each expression you have.
[image: Example]